# Is There a Way To Deobfuscate IronBrew Obfucator Version 2.7.2?

Tags: lua, deobfuscation

Is there a way to deobfuscate this?

````
    --[[
IronBrew:tm: obfuscation; Version 2.7.2
]]
return(function(stoptrynacracknignog_lIlIIIllIlI,stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll,stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll)local stoptrynacracknignog_IlIlllllllII=string.char;local stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI=string.sub;local stoptrynacracknignog_lIllllIIIIlIlIllIIIllll=table.concat;local stoptrynacracknignog_lIlllllllI=math.ldexp;local stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIIllIllIIII=getfenv or function()return _ENV end;local stoptrynacracknignog_lIllIIllIIllIlIIIl=select;local stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIlIlllIllllllIllIIl=unpack or table.unpack;local stoptrynacracknignog_lIllIIlIlllIIIIl=tonumber;local function stoptrynacracknignog_lIIlIllIIll(stoptrynacracknignog_lIlIIIllIlI)local stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll,stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI,stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII="","",{}local stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIIllIlIllI=256;local stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIlIlllIllllllIllIIl={}for stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=0,stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIIllIlIllI-1 do stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIlIlllIllllllIllIIl[stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll]=stoptrynacracknignog_IlIlllllllII(stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll)end;local stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=1;local function stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIlllIlIlII()local stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll=stoptrynacracknignog_lIllIIlIlllIIIIl(stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI(stoptrynacracknignog_lIlIIIllIlI,stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll,stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll),36)stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll+1;local stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI=stoptrynacracknignog_lIllIIlIlllIIIIl(stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI(stoptrynacracknignog_lIlIIIllIlI,stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll,stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll+stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll-1),36)stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll+stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll;return stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI end;stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll=stoptrynacracknignog_IlIlllllllII(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIlllIlIlII())stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII[1]=stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll;while stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll<#stoptrynacracknignog_lIlIIIllIlI do local stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIlllIlIlII()if stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIlIlllIllllllIllIIl[stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll]then stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI=stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIlIlllIllllllIllIIl[stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll]else stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI=stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll..stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll,1,1)end;stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIlIlllIllllllIllIIl[stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIIllIlIllI]=stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll..stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI,1,1)stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII[#stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII+1],stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll,stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIIllIlIllI=stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI,stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI,stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIIllIlIllI+1 end;return table.concat(stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII)end;local stoptrynacracknignog_lIllIIlIlllIIIIl=stoptrynacracknignog_lIIlIllIIll('21T21V27521S21W27521V21D21221E21I21627B21U27523721N1T25624X1221Y27922921S27927H27522927527H27427928027U280283284282283');local stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=(bit or bit32);local stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII=stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll and stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll.bxor or function(stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll,stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll)local stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI,stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII,stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI=1,0,10 while stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll>0 and stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll>0 do local stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIlIlllIllllllIllIIl,stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI=stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll%2,stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll%2 if stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIlIlllIllllllIllIIl~=stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI then stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII=stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII+stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI end stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll,stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll,stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI=(stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll-stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIlIlllIllllllIllIIl)/2,(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll-stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI)/2,stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI*2 end if stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll<stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll then stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll end while stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll>0 do local stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll=stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll%2 if stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll>0 then stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII=stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII+stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI end stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll,stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI=(stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll-stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll)/2,stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI*2 end return stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII end local function stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI,stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll,stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll)if stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll then local stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI/2^(stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll-1))%2^((stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll-1)-(stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll-1)+1);return stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll-stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll%1;else local stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=2^(stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll-1);return(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI%(stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll+stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll)>=stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll)and 1 or 0;end;end;local stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=1;local function stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll()local stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIlIlllIllllllIllIIl,stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI,stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI,stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll=stoptrynacracknignog_lIlIIIllIlI(stoptrynacracknignog_lIllIIlIlllIIIIl,stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll,stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll+3);stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIlIlllIllllllIllIIl=stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII(stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIlIlllIllllllIllIIl,67)stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI=stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII(stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI,67)stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI=stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI,67)stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll=stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll,67)stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll+4;return(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll*16777216)+(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI*65536)+(stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI*256)+stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIlIlllIllllllIllIIl;end;local function stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIlllIlIlII()local stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll=stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII(stoptrynacracknignog_lIlIIIllIlI(stoptrynacracknignog_lIllIIlIlllIIIIl,stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll,stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll),67);stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll+1;return stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll;end;local function stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIIllIlIllI()local stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI,stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll=stoptrynacracknignog_lIlIIIllIlI(stoptrynacracknignog_lIllIIlIlllIIIIl,stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll,stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll+2);stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI=stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI,67)stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll=stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll,67)stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll+2;return(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll*256)+stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI;end;local function stoptrynacracknignog_IlIllIIIIlllIIlIllI()local stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll();local stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll=stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll();local stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI=1;local stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII=(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll,1,20)*(2^32))+stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll;local stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll,21,31);local stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll=((-1)^stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll,32));if(stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll==0)then if(stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII==0)then return stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll*0;else stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=1;stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI=0;end;elseif(stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll==2047)then return(stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII==0)and(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll*(1/0))or(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll*(0/0));end;return stoptrynacracknignog_lIlllllllI(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll,stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll-1023)*(stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI+(stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII/(2^52)));end;local stoptrynacracknignog_lIIlIllIIll=stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll;local function stoptrynacracknignog_lllIllIllIIIIllIlIIIIl(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll)local stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI;if(not stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll)then stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll=stoptrynacracknignog_lIIlIllIIll();if(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll==0)then return'';end;end;stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI=stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI(stoptrynacracknignog_lIllIIlIlllIIIIl,stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll,stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll+stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll-1);stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll+stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll;local stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll={}for stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=1,#stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI do stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll[stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll]=stoptrynacracknignog_IlIlllllllII(stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII(stoptrynacracknignog_lIlIIIllIlI(stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI,stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll,stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll)),67))end return stoptrynacracknignog_lIllllIIIIlIlIllIIIllll(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll);end;local stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll;local function stoptrynacracknignog_lIlllllllI(...)return{...},stoptrynacracknignog_lIllIIllIIllIlIIIl('#',...)end local function stoptrynacracknignog_lIllIIlIlllIIIIl()local stoptrynacracknignog_lIlIIIllIlI={};local stoptrynacracknignog_IlIlllllllII={};local stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll={};local stoptrynacracknignog_lIIlIllIIll={[#{{622;103;337;507};"1 + 1 = 111";}]=stoptrynacracknignog_IlIlllllllII,[#{"1 + 1 = 111";"1 + 1 = 111";{548;922;421;421};}]=nil,[#{"1 + 1 = 111";{735;22;112;976};{499;336;447;503};{135;609;506;896};}]=stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll,[#{{76;258;383;106};}]=stoptrynacracknignog_lIlIIIllIlI,};local stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll()local stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI={}for stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI=1,stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll do local stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll=stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIlllIlIlII();local stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll;if(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll==0)then stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIlllIlIlII()~=0);elseif(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll==1)then stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=stoptrynacracknignog_IlIllIIIIlllIIlIllI();elseif(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll==3)then stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=stoptrynacracknignog_lllIllIllIIIIllIlIIIIl();end;stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI[stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI]=stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll;end;for stoptrynacracknignog_lIllIIlIlllIIIIl=1,stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll()do local stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIlllIlIlII();if(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI(stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll,1,1)==0)then local stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII=stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI(stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll,2,3);local stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIlIlllIllllllIllIIl=stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI(stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll,4,6);local stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll={stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIIllIlIllI(),stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIIllIlIllI(),nil,nil};if(stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII==0)then stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("l0X")]=stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIIllIlIllI();stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("uhEB")]=stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIIllIlIllI();elseif(stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII==1)then stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("IhU")]=stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll();elseif(stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII==2)then stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("VfF")]=stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll()-(2^16)elseif(stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII==3)then stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#{"1 + 1 = 111";{830;96;205;134};{943;530;687;937};}]=stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll()-(2^16)stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("5zvm")]=stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIIllIlIllI();end;if(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI(stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIlIlllIllllllIllIIl,1,1)==1)then stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("xR")]=stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI[stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("mM")]]end if(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI(stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIlIlllIllllllIllIIl,2,2)==1)then stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("RoL")]=stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI[stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("FQH")]]end if(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI(stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIlIlllIllllllIllIIl,3,3)==1)then stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("ldAC")]=stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI[stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("Udq9")]]end stoptrynacracknignog_lIlIIIllIlI[stoptrynacracknignog_lIllIIlIlllIIIIl]=stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll;end end;for stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=1,stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll()do stoptrynacracknignog_IlIlllllllII[stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll-1]=stoptrynacracknignog_lIllIIlIlllIIIIl();end;stoptrynacracknignog_lIIlIllIIll[3]=stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIlllIlIlII();return stoptrynacracknignog_lIIlIllIIll;end;local function stoptrynacracknignog_IlIlllllllII(stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll,stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll,stoptrynacracknignog_lIlIIIllIlI)stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=(stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll==true and stoptrynacracknignog_lIllIIlIlllIIIIl())or stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll;return(function(...)local stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI=stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[1];local stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII=stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[3];local stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[2];local stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=stoptrynacracknignog_lIlllllllI local stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI=1;local stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIIllIlIllI=-1;local stoptrynacracknignog_IlIlllllllII={};local stoptrynacracknignog_lIllIIlIlllIIIIl={...};local stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIlllIlIlII=stoptrynacracknignog_lIllIIllIIllIlIIIl('#',...)-1;local stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll={};local stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll={};for stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=0,stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIlllIlIlII do if(stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll>=stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII)then stoptrynacracknignog_IlIlllllllII[stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll-stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII]=stoptrynacracknignog_lIllIIlIlllIIIIl[stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll+1];else stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll[stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll]=stoptrynacracknignog_lIllIIlIlllIIIIl[stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll+#{"1 + 1 = 111";}];end;end;local stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIlllIlIlII-stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII+1 local stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll;local stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII;while true do stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI[stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI];stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII=stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("6")];if stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII<=#("OFrq")then if stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII<=#("i")then if stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII>#("")then local stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI=stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("NA")];do return stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll[stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI](stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIlIlllIllllllIllIIl(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll,stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI+1,stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("jRX")]))end;else stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll[stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#{{899;957;79;290};{10;761;506;190};}]]=stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("Qtr")];end;elseif stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII<=#("pe")then stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll[stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("X8")]]=stoptrynacracknignog_lIlIIIllIlI[stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("PWE")]];elseif stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII>#("W80")then stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll[stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("IM")]]=stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#{"1 + 1 = 111";"1 + 1 = 111";{863;17;422;555};}];else local stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII;stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll[stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("M1")]]=stoptrynacracknignog_lIlIIIllIlI[stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("RVM")]];stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI=stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI+1;stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI[stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI];stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll[stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("P1")]]=stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("Ns8")];stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI=stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI+1;stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI[stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI];stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII=stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("Gx")];do return stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll[stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII](stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIlIlllIllllllIllIIl(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll,stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII+1,stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("axL")]))end;stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI=stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI+1;stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI[stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI];stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII=stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("B5")];do return stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIlIlllIllllllIllIIl(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll,stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII,stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIIllIlIllI)end;stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI=stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI+1;stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=stoptrynacracknignog_lIIIIIlIllI[stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI];do return end;end;elseif stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII<=#("G7biqIS")then if stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII<=#("5KO5R")then do return end;elseif stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII==#("MOW4ot")then local stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI=stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("vh")];do return stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll[stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI](stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIlIlllIllllllIllIIl(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll,stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI+1,stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("Cas")]))end;else stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll[stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("gl")]]=stoptrynacracknignog_lIlIIIllIlI[stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("tkT")]];end;elseif stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII<=#("IGDGX60n")then do return end;elseif stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIlllIllIIlllIllII>#("SIAuglSyJ")then local stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("1s")];do return stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIlIlllIllllllIllIIl(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll,stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll,stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIIllIlIllI)end;else local stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll=stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll[#("dm")];do return stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIlIlllIllllllIllIIl(stoptrynacracknignog_IIIIIlIIllIIIllIll,stoptrynacracknignog_llllIIIIIllIIIllll,stoptrynacracknignog_llIlIIllIlIllI)end;end;stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI=stoptrynacracknignog_IIIlIIlIIllIIIlIIlIlI+1;end;end);end;return stoptrynacracknignog_IlIlllllllII(true,{},stoptrynacracknignog_IIlIIIllIllIIII())();end)(string.byte,table.insert,setmetatable);```
````

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is way, but you must do it manually, step by step, and know how Lua works. Everything that a computer can read, a human can also, but not in a short period of time.

The first step is to use some kind of beautifier (there are some online if you look on Google).

Next you should make the code easier to read, in your case the first command is a return function with 3 args, where the last 2 have the same name, and at the end you have an execute with `string.byte,table.insert,setmetatable`, so you should put these functions in place of arguments and cut of function.

You must remember about overriding variables, so you can't use just auto-replace for this. And after many hours, you should have nice code to read.